# Error CS0006: Metadata file 'Microsoft.CSharp' could not be found

Tags: .net, fastreport, asp.net-webpages

I am compiling my .net project on my local computer using visual studio 2019 it does not give any error, I publish it again, it does not give an error. I publish it on the windows server, the method I call works. After a few hours, when I call the same method, I get an Error **”CS0006: Metadata file 'Microsoft.CSharp' could not be found error.”**

I did the cleaning and recompiling of the project to solve the error. I also use fast report in the project. Could it be caused by fast report?

The solutions I found on the internet do not work either, as I do not get an error at the time of compilation. Could it be a server related issue?

Comment: I've seen this error with Fast Report. There's a couple of workarounds here: https://github.com/FastReports/FastReport/issues/377